# Python: Reading in Dictionary from Textfile

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an ugly problem I've come across. I'm being fed the following text file, which is output from another Python file. From that previous file, it's a dictionary that was spit out into this text file.

**Text file (named 'output.txt'):**

```
0:[([(11, 191), (11, 170), (14, 170), (11, 188)], [0.7830932724146064, 0.7789413675533634, 0.7714495149543579, 0.7688444764225846])]
90:[([(95, 170), (95, 2), (119, 2), (95, 146)], [0.7830932724146064, 0.7789413675533634, 0.7714495149543579, 0.7688444764225846])]
180:[([(182, 2), (182, 23), (179, 23), (182, 5)], [0.7830932724146064, 0.7789413675533634, 0.7714495149543579, 0.7688444764225846])]
270:[([(98, 23), (98, 191), (74, 191), (98, 47)], [0.7830932724146064, 0.7789413675533634, 0.7714495149543579, 0.7688444764225846])]
```

I'm fairly familiar with reading in text files, but this one has me stumped. The silly thing about this whole problem is that I actually need the file to be given to me in a dictionary format, so I'm basically just trying to read in the file as it was given to me. **The problem is when reading it in, Python doesn't know it's a dictionary and instead gives me strings.** Is there anyway to have the values of the dictionary read in as a list of lists instead of just a string (shown below)? Thanks very much!

```
d = {}
with open("output.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        d_line = line.rstrip('\n').split(':')
        d[int(d_line[0])] = d_line[1]

print(d)

{0: '[([(11, 191), (11, 170), (14, 170), (11, 188)], [0.7830932724146064, 0.7789413675533634, 0.7714495149543579, 0.7688444764225846])]', 90: '[([(95, 170), (95, 2), (119, 2), (95, 146)], [0.7830932724146064, 0.7789413675533634, 0.7714495149543579, 0.7688444764225846])]', 180: '[([(182, 2), (182, 23), (179, 23), (182, 5)], [0.7830932724146064, 0.7789413675533634, 0.7714495149543579, 0.7688444764225846])]', 270: '[([(98, 23), (98, 191), (74, 191), (98, 47)], [0.7830932724146064, 0.7789413675533634, 0.7714495149543579, 0.7688444764225846])]'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, yo can use `ast.literal_eval` to interpret the rest:

```
import ast
d = {}
with open("output.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
      d_line = line.rstrip('\n').split(':')
      d[int(d_line[0])] = ast.literal_eval(d_line[1])

print(d)
```

Or in one line:

```
new_d = {int(key):ast.literal_eval(values) for key, values in [i.strip('\n').split(':') for i in open('output.txt')]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) here:

```
dict_from_file = {}
with open('output.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        d_line = line.rstrip('\n')
        dict_from_file.update(eval('{{{0}}}'.format(d_line)))
```

Or to keep it compact:

```
with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
    dict_from_file = eval('{{{0}}}'.format(','.join(f.readlines()))
```

Please note though: `eval` is not a save method. **If you are not absolutely sure about the content you feed `eval`, don't use it!**

A saver alternative is [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). You can use it just as `eval` here.

**The best approach in this case would be to not have the first script write the dictionaries as plain text.** Using something like [pickles](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) is both saver and simpler!